# javascript / jQuery hide if html equals 0

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, wordpress

I've built this site [www.piano-warehouse.co.uk/category/upright-pianos/](http://www.piano-warehouse.co.uk/category/upright-pianos/) using Wordpress and have utilised a plugin for calculating the amount of money saved if a discount has been applied to a product. I would like to modify the setup so that if no discount has been applied and there is no amount saved to hide the you save section. I assume javascript or jQuery will be the ticket however I have a very elementary understanding of these languages and would really appreciate any help with constructing this query.

So far I've tried adding this to my functions file with no joy

```
function you_save_hide () {
    if ($("span.yousave_list_price").text() == "0") {
        $("span.yousave_list").hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: include html as well

Comment: And i guess the `"span.yousave_list_price"` should be hidden too?!

Comment: You should maybe hide a div, instead of 1+ span(s). Please show your html

Comment: How does "HTML equals 0"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the link I can see if `$("span.yousave_list_price")` contains another DOM element

```
<span class="yousave_list_price">
<span class="amount">Some Value</span>
</span>
```

So if you are looking to hide this `span.yousave_list_price` you may have to do like this

```
var _getAmountList = $('.amount');
_getAmountList.each(function(){
// equalizing with £0 just for demo
// You can use regex with fine tune it.
if($(this).text().trim() ==="£0"){ 
  $(this).parent().hide()
}
})
```

[JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/hssk3fss/)

Answer (score 0):

I checked your website, span.yousave_list_price is the next element to span.yousave_list and I am sure you didn't wish to hide all the span.yousave_list of 0. But only those which has span.yousave_list_price. So we will select all the span.yousave_list_price -> check if the text is 0 -> then we select it's parent and -> within the parent we hide the span.yousave_list.

```
function you_save_hide () {
    $("span.yousave_list_price").each(function(){
        if ($(this).text().trim() == "0"){
            $(this).parent().closest("span.yousave_list").hide(); //hide the nearest .yousave_list when the yousave_list_price equals 0
        }
    });
}
```

if you are executing this function on page load then be sure to call it within `$(document).ready(function(){...}`

Answer (score 0):

you must ensure that the page is ready when calling this function

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    you_save_hide();
});
```